# How to remove empty elements except one

Tags: xml, xslt

input:

```
<Request>
    <name>johndoe</name>
    <Line />
    <address>      
        <operator/>
        <line1>XYZ</line1>
        <line2 />
        <city>ABC</city>
        <state>FL</state>
        <zipCode />
        <desc />
        <email />
        <phone />
    </address>
</Request>
```

Output:

```
<Request>
    <name>johndoe</name>
    <address>      
        <operator>NULL</operator>
        <line1>XYZ</line>
        <city>ABC</city>
        <state>FL</state>
    </address>
</Request>
```

I need to remove all empty elements except operator, if it is empty I need to pass NULL otherwise need to pass whatever is input

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="operator[not(text())]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:text>NULL</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Removes empty nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//text() | .//@*)]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this removes operator element too. how to proceed to remove except operator and inject NULL if operator is empty

Comment: Templates cannot be nested.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this with single xsl instead of two xsl's. I know we can do transform this output with other xsl again removing empty ones there

Comment: It seems that after editing you solved the problem. Doesn't the stylesheet above produce the results you expect? See http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BM

Comment: wierd. In xmlspy it wont work and also in other tool which I use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="operator[not(text())]" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>NULL</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Removes empty nodes -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(.//text() | .//@*)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="operator[not(text())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>NULL</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Removes empty nodes -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(.//text() | .//@*)][not(self::operator)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```